# JMeter can I run it locally?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In my opinion, load tests should be performed from several different IP addresses simultaneously(because of restrictions on http). Am I right?

I will do load tests for:
Number of Threads (users):  2000
Ramp-Up Period (in seconds): 10

Answer (score 2):

The load doesn't necessarily have to come from different IP addresses however depending on your application nature it might be required (for example application does explicit check of origin IP address or lives behind a [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) with session stickiness based on IP addresses or whatever)

In this case you can perform [IP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) so each request would come from the different IP address, you can configure source IP address under "Source address" input on the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image: HTTP Request JMeter Source Address]

See [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run JMeter locally, it can be run anywhere that has a Java Virtual Machine.

Another alternative if you are interested is Gatling http://gatling.io/

Answer (score 1):

To perform load test in serveral different IP address use [Jmeter remote test](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

```
control multiple, remote JMeter engines from a single JMeter client. By running JMeter remotely, you can replicate a test across many low-end computers and thus simulate a larger load on the server.
```